# scroll to element in a long div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scrollable div that contains a table with many rows (100+).

I would like to be able to show the table row that contains the data I'm looking for via a jQuery filter.

I know the table row id.  How do I move the div down to the correct row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
document.getElementById(id).scrollIntoView(true);
```

It's part of the [CSSOM View Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/), it may not be supported in all browsers, but probably [all you care about](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t23) though.

Ooops missed the *row* in *row id*. If you have a reference to the table, then:

```
table.rows[rowId].scrollIntoView(true);
```

Comment: this is very close to working for me (1st example).  I'm getting a little wierdness in the fact that it jumps my screen up some and the highlighted row is actually 1 under the top of the div now (so now in order to see it I have to scroll up).  Any ideas on how to make these minor adjustments?

Comment: I changed scrollIntoView(true) to scrollIntoView(false) and everything works a lot better!  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('html, body').scrollTop($('#rowId').offset().top);
```

If you want litte animation:

```
$('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $("#rowId").offset().top
}, 2000);    // 2000 is the duration of animation in milliseconds
```